# System of coupled second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I need to solve this differential system :
$ x''+\lambda_1 x' + kx=\alpha + ky$
$y''+\lambda_2 y' + ky = \beta + kx$
with null initial conditions and where $ \lambda_i,k,\alpha,\beta$ are all real parameters but unknown. How would you solve this system? I've tried to transform as a first order system, but the eigenvalues are tedious to compute. Many thanks.

Comment: Consider it as a single system with four variables and solve it. And what do you mean by 'solve' for unknown parameters? Solve symbolically?

Comment: @Moo problem with this approach, is that I have to find the roots (one is zero) of a fourth order polynomial with 3 parameters! Same holds for the solution proposed by Arastas.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ q_1(t) = x(t) $, $ q_2(t) = \dot{x}(t) $, $ q_3(t) = y(t) $, $ q_4(t) = \dot{y}(t) $, and $ q(t) = \left[ q_1(t), q_2(t), q_3(t), q_4(t) \right]^{T} $. Then, we can rewrite the ordinary differential equation as a first order ODE in the state-space form
$$ \begin{align} \dot{q}(t) &= \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -k & -\lambda_1 & k & 0\\ 0 &0 & 0 & 1 \\ k & 0 & -k & -\lambda_2 \end{matrix} \right]q(t) + \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{matrix} \right] \\ &\triangleq A q(t) + B u \end{align} $$
for which the solution is given by
$$ q(t) = e^{A(t - t_0)} q(t_0) + \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu d\tau. $$
where $ q(t_0) $ is the initial condition.

Comment: As already pointed out, the problem is to compute the eiegenvalues. We would need to find the roots of a parametric third degree polynomial, which is not easy to factorize.